# http response include set cookie jession id, but then send a request, there is no cookie info in the request header

Tags: http, cookies, jsessionid

browser: IE11.
server: tomcat + nginx

first request response:

```
   cache: no-cache
   Connection: keep-alive
   Content-Type: image/png
   Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 10:47:43 GMT
   Server: Tengine/2.1.1
   Set-Cookie: _uid=CiMDa1cxvE+jjDeFAw56Ag==; path=/
   Set-Cookie: _uid=eff37cac39ac062caba9b5ec2c8a00f4;Path=/
   Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AEBC40BA0AD98AA787CC011F3029307C; Path=/; HttpOnly
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

after this request, the cookie JSESSIONID should be store in the browser,
but when a send the 2nd request, the JSESSIONID is not included in the request header.and the response header, server set another JSESSIONID.

ps:
there is no problem in chrome.
there is no problem when request to the tomcat directly by IE.

can someone help me....   :(

Comment: Check in your IE bodgguer the requests send, you may query 2 different domain, either the name, or just the port changes.

Comment: @Walfrat I've not request 2 domain, the port is not changed too.the request is made by javascript to change the captcha, javascript is as this: $img.attr('src','/captcha/get.do?t='+ new Date().getTime());

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, because the domain contain a '_', just like this：xx_xx.xx.com.
IE won't store the cookie set by this kind of domain.
I've change the domain and tested, it can work now.